# Execution context and object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, executioncontext

There's something about object, execution context in JS that I don't understand.

When we create an object, does it create an execution context ? since an execution context is created when a function is invoked. And if it doesn't, so the object is just like the others variable in the actual execution context ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When we create an object, does it create an execution context ?

No.

> since an execution context is created when a function is invoked.

That's true, but creating an object is different from invoking a function.

> And if it doesn't, so the object is just like the others variable in the actual execution context ?

The object exists in memory, and a *reference* to it exists in any variable or property you stored it in. If you store it in a variable, that variable is held in a *lexical environment object* associated the execution context where the variable was declared.

A concrete example might help:

```
function foo() {
    var n = 42;
    var o = {};
    console.log(n, o.toString()); // 42, [object Object]
}
foo();
```

Calling `foo` creates an execution context and a lexical environment object associated with it. The `n` and `o` variables are *bindings* stored in that lexical environment. The `n` binding's value is the primitive number 42. The `o` binding's value is a *reference* to the object. The object itself exists elsewhere in memory.

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Execution Context  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Current Lex Env    |−−>| Lexical Environment |
| (some other stuff) |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   | n: 42               |   +−−−−−−−−+
                         | o                   |−−>| Object |
                         | (some other stuff)  |   +−−−−−−−−+
                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

But again, that context and its lexical environment are created by the call to `foo`, not by creating an object.

Once `foo` returns, if no closures were created within `foo`, the execution context and its associated lexical environment are eligible for garbage collection.

Getting a bit far afield of your question: If we'd created a closure within `foo` and retained a reference to it even after `foo` returned, the lexical environment would be retained by that closure; more on closures in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: for the detailed explanation (+1)